# Debugging a SQL Query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table structure like below. I need to select the row where `User_Id =100` and `User_sub_id = 1` and `time_used = minimum of all` and where `Timestamp` the highest. The output of my query should result in :

```
US;1365510103204;NY;1365510103;100;1;678;
```

My query looks like this.

```
select * 
from my_table 
where CODE='DE' 
  and User_Id = 100 
  and User_sub_id = 1 
 and time_used = (select min(time_used) 
                  from my_table 
                  where CODE='DE' 
                    and User_Id=100 
                    and User_sub_id= 1);
```

this returns me all the 4 rows. I need only 1, the one with highest timestamp.
Many Thanks

```
CODE:   Timestamp:  Location:   Time_recorded:  User_Id:    User_sub_Id:    time_used
"US;1365510102420;NY;1365510102;100;1;1078;
"US;1365510102719;NY;1365510102;100;1;978;
"US;1365510103204;NY;1365510103;100;1;878;
"US;1365510102232;NY;1365510102;100;1;678;
"US;1365510102420;NY;1365510102;100;1;678;
"US;1365510102719;NY;1365510102;100;1;678;
"US;1365510103204;NY;1365510103;100;1;678;
"US;1365510102420;NY;1365510102;101;1;678;
"US;1365510102719;NY;1365510102;101;1;638;
"US;1365510103204;NY;1365510103;101;1;638;
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. Postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then try this:

```
select *
from my_table
where CODE='DE'
  and User_Id=100
  and User_sub_id=1
  and time_used=(
    select min(time_used)
    from my_table
    where CODE='DE'
    and User_Id=100 and User_sub_id=1
  )
order by "timestamp" desc --   <-- this adds sorting
limit 1; --   <-- this retrieves only one row
```

Comment: You don't necessarily need a group by when using an aggregate function.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: thanks for the info, I thought it was required.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: thanks for the correction, I never used Postgres but only mysql, and always used ` for column names escape.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibly faster solution is using window functions:

```
select * 
from (
  select code,
         timestamp,
         min(time_used) over (partition by user_id, user_sub_id) as min_used,
         row_number() over (partition by user_id, user_sub_id order by timestamp desc) as rn,
         time_used,
         user_id, 
         user_sub_id
  from my_table 
  where CODE='US' 
    and User_Id = 100 
    and User_sub_id = 1 
) t
where time_used = min_used
  and rn = 1;
```

This only needs to scan the table once instead of twice as your solution with the sub-select is doing.

I would strongly recommend to rename the column `timestamp`.

First this is a reserved word and using them is not recommended.

And secondly it doesn't document anything - it's horrible name as such. `time_used` is much better and you should find something similar for `timestamp`. Is that the "recording time", the "expiration time", the "due time" or something completely different?

Comment: thanks for the answer and as you pointed out, the column is actually not named as 'timestamp',it is called 'calculation_begin_timestamp' as it was too long, I just used 'timestamp'.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your query the following condition

> ORDER BY Timestamp DESC, LIMIT 1